# Maintaining attributes in feature class in memory using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, in-memory

i am trying to feature to line conversion  that are not multipart lines and Merge output feature class but its loses the attributes.

Here is my code:

```
arcpy.env.workspace="in_memory/" 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(LINEFEATURECLASS,['shape@']) as sip:
    i=0
    for row in sip:   
        geom=row[0]   
        if not geom.isMultipart:  
            op="polyLine"+str(i)
            arcpy.FeatureToLine_management(geom,op,"0.001 Meters","ATTRIBUTES")                      
            i=i+1
    fclist=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","Polyline")
    Merge=arcpy.Merge_management(fclist,"D://Merge_Polyline")
```

Tool working but it losing attributes.

Comment: I'm assuming that it's geometry attributes that you are losing.

Comment: it's losing all fields information

Comment: If I have understood the intention of this script I think a much better approach would be to dispense with using an in_memory workspace and multiple invocations of the FeatureToLine tool and instead run a simultaneous InsertCursor that writes only those features (with their attributes) that meet your criteria.  Alternatively if you can add a field and populate it with a flag that designates multipart features (perhaps using Field Calculator which is geometry aware) then a simple Select_analysis will do the rest.